# How to parse a concatenated a zone file

Tags: python, parsing, dns, zone

I have a large zone file that I want to move to another provider. My issue is the export is only one large concatenated zone file where as my new registrar only accepts single standard zone files.

For example allzone.txt contains:

```
somedomain.com
=========
Record data...
...
------------
anotherdomain.com
=========
Record data...
...
------------
evenmoredomain.com
=========
Record data...
...
------------
```

What I'd like to happen is that it takes the one file above and creates 3 files.

```
somedomain.txt
anotherdomain.com.txt
evenmoredomain.com.txt
```

Inside each of the files the delimiters of :

```
anydomain.com
========= 
and 
------------
```

are removed only leaving

```
"Record data"
```

Between.

So a file should be named domainA.com.txt and inside just the corresponding record data.

Not sure what the best way to do this. I can split on a delimiter but not sure how to take that content to write a new file where the name is what is before the delimiter (anydomain.com)

Thanks!

Comment: show your code.

Comment: get line by line. When you find `domain` string then open new file (and close previous file if it was open) and write next lines to this file (and still check every line if there is new `domain`) - so you need `for line in file` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less

```
current_file = None

with open('allzone.txt') as f:

    # read line by line
    for line in f:

        # open next file and close previous
        if line.startswith('domain'):
            # close previous file
            if current_file:
                current_file.close()
            # open new file
            current_file = open(line.strip() + '.txt', 'w')

        # write to current file
        if current_file:
            if not (line.startswith('domain') or line.startswith('---') or line.startswith('===')):
                current_file.write(line)

    # close last file
    if current_file:
        current_file.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** new version for any domain

```
current_file = None

with open('allzone.txt') as f:

    # read line by line
    for line in f:

        # open next file
        if not current_file:
            # open new file
            current_file = open(line.strip() + '.txt', 'w')
            # skip next line 
            next(f) 
        else:
            # close previous file
            if line.startswith('---') :
                current_file.close()
                current_file = None
            # write records    
            #elif not line.startswith('==='): # use it if you don't use `next(f)` 
            else:
                current_file.write(line)

    # close last file
    if current_file:
        current_file.close()
```

Comment: I guess theres a little bit of confusion I'll fixed my example. domainA,B,C.com is really anything.com so I can't use the flag of startswith 'domain'. I'll edit my question.

Comment: my answer doesn't use the startswith so in theory should handle any domain name on that first line

Comment: @chowpay new version for any domains

Comment: @furas this is perfect but im confused on how this part works. `open(line.strip()..)` when you strip the first line that contains  domainname.com but you dont define parameters inside the `strip()` What is it doing? For example if I had a string xxxx123123.com and strip(x) I would get 123123.com I assume.

Comment: `strip()`  as default removes whitespaces - newlines, tabs, spaces. When you read line from file then you alwasy get line with `\n` at the end - so I remove it.

Comment: @furas the files that get written out all have `?` ie. `domain.com?.txt`  where does the ? come from.

Comment: check in `allzone.txt`. Maybe you have `?` in this file. Or maybe file use some encoding and you have to decode line before you use it.

Comment: you can add `print(line, line.strip())` in code to see what you get.

Comment: Fixed the problem looks like there strip didnt get rid of the \n for some reason. Heres the line replaced `current_file = open(line.strip() + '.txt', 'w')` with  `fn = '{0}.txt'.format(line.strip('Zone: ').rstrip('\n'))
current_file = open(fn, 'w')`  it looks to be writing out the file correctly now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work? It might still need some tweaking

```
def main():
    with open('allzone.txt', 'r+') as f:
        data = ''
        first_line = ''
        for line in f:
            if first_line == '':
                first_line = line
            elif line == '------------\n':
                new_file = open('%s.txt' % first_line.rstrip(), 'w+')
                new_file.write(data)
                new_file.close()
                first_line = ''
                data = ''
            elif line == '=========\n' or line == '...\n' or line == '------------\n':
                pass
            else:
                data += line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```